# Garbage Collection works automatically or manually?

Tags: java, object, garbage

I want to ask if garbage collector automatically deletes unused objects in a Java program or it should be manually done by assigning an object to null?

Comment: It is automatically done in Java. Null assignment is needed only for programming logic and not for garbage collection.

Comment: Automatically  ...

Comment: Setting a variable to null is not deleting an object, but it may allow a now-unreferenced object to be automatically garbage collected.

Comment: Setting a variable to null is like deleting somebody's phone number from your phone: you can't call it any more, but their phone still exists, and can be called by anybody else who happens to have their number.

Comment: @SandyC - *"Null assignment is needed only for programming logic and not for garbage collection. "*  Not quite.  There are some occasions where assigning a null avoids a memory leak; e.g. look at the source code for `ArrayList.clear()` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html)

> In a programming language like C, allocating and deallocating memory is a manual process. In Java, process of deallocating memory is handled automatically by the garbage collector.

I'd suggest you reading the full article. You will have a good grasp of how GC works in Java. HTH.